# Intersect not giving expected results

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In the below code if I iterated over L3 I would expect to have 2 results available. However it only has one result and that result is the objTest with a Id = 9. I thought it should be a result set with two objtest s'  Id = 9  and Id = 10.

```
class Program
{
public class objTest 
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool On  { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
class PramComp : EqualityComparer<objTest>
{
    public override bool Equals(objTest x, objTest y)
    {
        return x.Value == y.Value;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode(objTest obj)
    {
        return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<objTest> L1 = new List<objTest>();
    L1.Add(new objTest { Value = 1, On = true ,Id =1});
    L1.Add(new objTest { Value = 2, On = false ,Id =2});
    L1.Add(new objTest { Value = 3, On = false, Id = 3 });
    L1.Add(new objTest { Value = 4, On = false ,Id =4});
    L1.Add(new objTest { Value = 5, On = false ,Id =5});

    List<objTest> L2 = new List<objTest>();
    L2.Add(new objTest { Value = 6, On = false ,Id =6});
    L2.Add(new objTest { Value = 7, On = false ,Id=7});
    L2.Add(new objTest { Value = 8, On = false,Id =8 });
    L2.Add(new objTest { Value = 1, On = true,Id =9 });
    L2.Add(new objTest { Value = 1, On = true, Id =10 });

    var L3 = L2.Intersect(L1, new PramComp());

}
}
```

So I have made a mistake with my code if I want to return the two results Id=9 and Id=10.
Could someone tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: Possible duplicate - [LINQ: Find all intersecting data, not just the unique values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2180054/1816426)

Comment: @KonradGadzina That question is similar, but there are different (unusual) criteria involved there.  That question wants the matches from BOTH collections in results.

Comment: @ReedCopsey You're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) is designed to produce:

> the set intersection of two sequences.

A "set" does not allow duplicate values, which means you'll only get one of the two values.

If you want to return both of the ones that match, you could use:

```
var L3 = L2.Where(item => L1.Any(one => one.Value == item.Value));
```

This will go through the `L2` collection and find all items which have any matching value in `L1`, but *preserve the duplicates*.

Comment: According to the documentation, `whose distinct elements that also appear in second will be returned.`

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: Correct, but the elements aren't distinct, under the equality definition provided.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich *distinct* is the key word there.  I pulled out the text from the page I linked on MSDN which discusses set semantics, but either wording means the same thing.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I'm not disagreeing with you, just pointing it out in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, `Reed Copsey` already pointed out where your incorrect assumption lies. However, his way of linking two lists is inefficient. `join` forms `dictioanry` to pair the elements so it is better to use it:

```
var l3 = from e2 in L2
         join e1 in L1 on e1.Value equals e2.Value
         into grp
         where grp.Any()
         select e2;
```

Comment: Yes but should be   'on e1.Value equals e2.Value' does the trick

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired results.  If there were duplicate items in `L1` matching at least one item in `L2` the items in `L2` would be duplicated.  This would then spit out the value multilpe times when it shouldn't.  You need to use a `GroupJoin` rather than a `Join`, and where there is at least a match, to produce the correct results.

Comment: @Servy You are right. I amended the answer. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Your equality comparer compares the Value property why id 9 and id 10 are considered the same element for the intersection. Thus there is only one element in common.