# Getting common values in two array issue using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, linq

I have two arrays say

```
var list1 = string[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "", ""};
var list2 = string[] {"2", "3", "4","",""};
```

When i try to get common items form these two array using following code

```
 var listCommon = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

It gives me result like this

```
string[] {"2", "3", "4", ""}
```

But i want it should return like this

```
string[] {"2", "3", "4", "", ""}
```

It is **escaping last empty string** value while intersecting.

Comment: Why would 1 be returned?

Comment: "1" is not a common item

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180054/linq-find-all-intersecting-data-not-just-the-unique-values

Comment: @DavidArno Actually that question is a little different.  That question would expect to get `{"2", "2", "3", "3, "4", "4", "", "", "", ""}` for the example given here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set methods like `Intersect` or `Except` remove duplicates from each collection. I assume you want something like this instead:

```
var listCommon = list1.Where(list2.Contains);
```

which is not as  efficient. This *could* be an optimization:

```
var l2Lookup = new HashSet<string>(list2);
var listCommon = list1.Where(l2Lookup.Contains);
```

Comment: Interesting. I notice you are less keen to close/delete questions when you are raking in the rep from it, Tim...

Comment: @DavidArno: I have no idea what you're talking about. I have not noticed the duplicate vote until now. But even if, do i get a downvote from you because i answer a question that you have voted to close ?

Comment: Of course if the second list only contains one empty string this would still return two empty strings, because the first list has two.  Not sure if that's exactly what the OP wants, but the other way would definitely be more complex.

Answer (score 7):

This will work:

```
list1.Where(x=>list2.Contains(x))
```

Comment: Too bad, i'm too late )

Comment: But your answer is better :) I cant understood what meens "list1.Where(l2Lookup.Contains)" in top answer.  But your answer made it clear. Thank you @Anarion

Comment: @Andrey Rybalkin Keep in mind that Solution in answer by Tim Schmelter is way more efficient, because it's much faster to search in HashSet.